# Laravel FromRequest the given value must be true or false

Tags: angular, laravel

i am sending boolean type date from angular frontend to laravel backend and i am using FormRequest for data validation.
here is the data i send from angular:

```
{'full_name' : searchTerm,'is_search_friend':true}
```

FormRequest

```
  'full_name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:50',
  'is_search_friend' => 'required|boolean'
```

i get this error :

> is_search_friend: [" is search friend must be true or false"]

meanwhile i am sending a boolean type data 'is-search_friend'

Comment: What is the type of the `first` property?

Comment: i updated the post could you check it now please ?

Comment: Is you sent data field 'is-search_friend'? It has to be 'Is_search_friend'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the data `{'full_name' : searchTerm,'is_search_friend':true}` as `multipart/formdata` then the the request must need to be like

```
{'full_name' : searchTerm,'is_search_friend':1} //1 for true 0 for false
```

of if you pass value as RAW JSON data then the request will be

```
{
"full_name" : "searchTerm",
"is_search_friend":true
}
```

Comment: JSON uses double quotes though

Comment: @brombeer yeah you"re right thanks..